# Laravel's `broadcast` function doing nothing

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, broadcast

Running Laravel 5.5, PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu with Apache2.

I have this line of code:

```
broadcast(new \App\Events\Event("test"));
```

And I have the broadcaster set to "log" in `/config/broadcasting.php`:

```
'default' => "log",
```

And I have `BroadcastServiceProvider` enabled in `app.php` in both places.

However, nothing is being logged in `storage/logs/laravel.log`. (other logs are appearing just fine)

I tried setting the broadcaster to `redis` as well, but broadcasting the event does not create a `redis` value/key pair, even though `Redis::set()` is working fine.

Am I missing a step? What else do I need to do to get the broadcast function working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the ShouldBroadcast Interface on the Event
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#using-example-application

For reference this is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I read through the documentation about 10 times, and somehow missed that. I was about to say it should be bolded in the documentation, but actually it already is. haha XD. Thanks.

Comment: @Funfare, tell me if this deviate from your intended answer and you can remove the update. I thought its good to give a sample of your question so in case the link breaks there's something to refer to.